# Why is there no general solution for the general 2nd order linear ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

We can always solve a general first order linear ODE:

$$y'(x)+a(x)y(x)=b(x).$$

I am looking for some intuition why the general 2nd order linear ODE

$$y''(x)+a(x)y'(x)+b(x)y(x)=c(x) $$

does not have a gerneral formula. Is it mathematically impossible, or is there a chance, that someone will find a general solution? If it is mathematically impossible, is there any intuitive explanation to this phenomenon?

Answer (score 2):

It is mathematically impossible. The proof goes (generally speaking) along the same lines as it is proved that there is no general formula to solve algebraic equations of degree 5 or up. All the details can be found in, e.g., [An introduction to differential algebra 
by Irving Kaplansky](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/2705612513).

Comment: Is there any other source? Can you explain it intuitively, why it is inpossible?

Comment: @MrYouMath You can google "differentiable algebra." About "intuitively" - do you understand "intuitively" why polynomials of degree 5 and up cannot have explicit formulas for the roots?